# QGIS 3 Select by Location - How to get map results as a list?

Tags: qgis, select-by-location, list, results

Can I and if so how can I get a list of QGIS 3 "Select by location" results in a list?

For example, I did an "Intersect" "Select by location"query of two data sets (about 250 land properties and second set is resource protection areas related to streams of water) to see if the geometries spatially intersect (share any portion of space - overlap or touch).

The query worked well on the map (after I chose to ignore errors) and I can see the results on the map (different color shows the intersect). Some just appear to touch and other properties intersect more while many do not intersect at all.

Can I get a list of the properties that intersect and even showing the amount of intersection of the properties with the resource protection areas?

Comment: To export the selected features as a list export them to a CSV file, just tick on export only selected fetaures. To compute the area of intersections must run the Intersection algorithm first and then compute the area of the output layer features geometries. Some queries to filter and sort intersected features can be made. Please try to advance in the process and edit the question to provide a bit more specific example of the task.

Comment: I am very new to QGIS.  So I have two layers, (1) real estate properties, which I also filtered to get a small list of properties and (2) water stream resource protection areas. I ran Select by Location on (1) and (2) and got a nice map result. How does one select the map features to start an export? I see the hand (pan) but I do not see a select or pointer. I cannot even click on a property to see what its data is, and I cannot find in the QGIS manual how to do this.

Comment: If you are selecting by location, you have made already a selection. Export the layer and tick on export only selected features. To see properties of features open the attribute table, or inquiry any feature. To select, there is a toolbar with selection buttons. Please, edit the question, include some screenshot or something to try to reproduce your instance. For very basic tasks read the user guide (https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/) or search in this site too.

Comment: How does one Export the layer? I looked the User Guide and found some but not all the answers. . I am trying to find out how to export a layer result using desktop version.

Comment: Right click to the layer name in the layers tree, Export, Save selected features as.

Comment: Thank you very much Gabriel - that worked!  It is a subtle thing to know the right click is the way.